# Find a power series representation for the function.

Tags: calculus, power-series

[image]

I'm not sure how to handle this problem. I got that the radius of convergence was 1/6, but I don't know how to represent the function as a power series.

I can modify it to look like the following:

x * 1/(1-(-6x))^2

[image]

I thought this would be the power series but apparently not.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Applying the formula for the *[binomial series representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{x}{(1+6x)^2}&=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-2}{n}(6x)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+1}{1}(-6x)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)(-6)^nx^{n+1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-6)^{n-1}nx^n\qquad\qquad\qquad |x|<\frac{1}{6}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the binomial series representation with $\alpha=-2$
  \begin{align*}
  (1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n\qquad\qquad |x|<1
  \end{align*}
- In (2) we use the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}(-1)^k
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we shift the index by one to obtain powers $x^n$ again

Comment: Sheesh. I wish I was taught it this way instead of the confusing way the book does it. THanks so much!

Comment: @dmscs: You're welcome! Thanks for your nice comment! :-)

Answer (score 1):

OK, let us start from the well-known formula

$$\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n, \quad |x|<1 \tag{1}$$

Next we obtain the series expansion

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1+x)^2} &= -\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1+x} 
= - \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n \\
&= -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(-1)^n x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n+1}x^{n-1} \\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n+1}x^{n-1}, \quad |x|<1
\end{align} \tag{2}$$

Multiply $(2)$ by $x$ to get

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x}{(1+x)^2} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n (-1)^{n-1} x^n, \quad |x|<1
\end{align} \tag{3}$$

Replacing $x$ with $6x$ in $(3)$ and multiplying by $\dfrac{1}{6}$ gives the final result

$$\frac{x}{(1+6x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n (-1)^{n-1} x^n, \quad |x|<\frac 16 \tag{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that : $\dfrac{x}{(1+6x)^2}= x\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(-\dfrac{1}{6(1+6x)}\right)$,and you have $\dfrac{1}{1+6x} = 1+(-6x) + (-6x)^2 +\cdots , |x| < \frac{1}{6}$