# Summation of a Progression

Tags: summation, arithmetic-progressions

The Progression is:

$0(n-0) + 1(n-1) + 3(n-2) + 6(n-3) + 10(n-4) + .... $

which can be represented as:

$\sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{i(i+1)}{2}(n-i)$

Is there a general formula for this summation?

Comment: $\sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{i(i+1)}{2}(n-i)=\frac{1}{24}n(n-1)(n+1)(n+2)$ by WolframAlpha.

Comment: How do you arrive at that?

Comment: Did you mean for the $n$ in the upper bound of summation to be the same as the $n$ in the summand? If not, it's an abuse of notation.

Comment: yes, they are the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Methods to compute $\sum_{k=1}^nk^p$ without Faulhaber's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035188/methods-to-compute-sum-k-1nkp-without-faulhabers-formula)

Comment: To neatly get @Yuta's result from WolframAlpha, you can apply [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) twice with the [hockey stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Comment: Also, your identity is a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1938753/177399

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sum_i \frac{i(i+1)}2(n-i)
&=\sum_i \binom{i+1}2(n+2-(i+2))
\\&=(n+2)\sum_i \binom{i+1}2-\sum_i (i+2)\binom{i+1}2
\\&=(n+2)\sum_i \binom{i+1}2-3\sum_i\binom{i+2}3
\\&\stackrel{\text{H.S.}}=(n+2)\binom{n+2}3-3\binom{n+3}4
\\&=(n+3)\binom{n+2}3-\binom{n+2}3-3\binom{n+3}4
\\&=4\binom{n+3}4-\binom{n+2}3-3\binom{n+3}4
\\&=\binom{n+3}4-\binom{n+2}3
\\&= \binom{n+2}4
\end{align}
$\stackrel{\text{H.S.}}=$ is the hockey stick identity.

Comment: +1. First line typo: $n+2-i\color{red}{-}2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{i(i+1)}{2}(n-i)=\sum_{i = 0}^n \frac1 {2}(i^2n-i^3+in-i^2)=(n-1)\sum i^2-\sum i^3+n\sum i
$. Now, $\sum i=\frac {n(n+1)} {2} ; \sum i^2=\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)} 6;\sum i^3= \frac {n^2(n+1)^2} 4$