# Expectation of time for an ace to appear

Tags: probability, probability-theory, card-games

This question appears in Zhou's A Practical Guide To Quantitative Finance Interviews.

> What is the expected number of cards that need to be turned over in a regular 52-card deck in order to see the first ace ?

In his solution Zhou labels the non-ace cards $1$ to $48$ and for each $i\in \{1,\ldots,48\}$ he defines the event $A_i$ "card $i$ is turned over before all the 4 aces". With these notations, we need to compute $1+\sum_{i=1}^{48} E[1_{A_i}] = 1+48P(A_1)$ by symmetry. Zhou then argues

> As shown in the following sequence, each card $i$ is equally likely to be in one of the five regions separated by 4 aces: $$1 \quad A \quad  2 \quad A \quad 3 \quad A \quad 4 \quad A \quad 5$$

hence $P(A_1) = \frac 15$.

I don't understand why it is obvious that $P(A_1) = \frac 15$. The locations of the aces are themselves random. Is Zhou using some kind of independence ?

Can someone provide additional insight, or a less handwavy argument ?

Comment: this has been asked many times on this site.  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138853/expected-number-of-cards-you-should-turn-before-finding-an-ace), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3331575/expected-number-of-draws-until-first-ace), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207556/expected-number-of-cards-turned-over-before-seeing-first-ace) for example.

Comment: To your specific point:  In a properly shuffled deck, any order of the five cards is equally likely.  Thus, in particular, any of the five cards is equally likely to appear first, hence the probability that a particular one appears first is $\frac 15$.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/245381/1147953) is illuminating.