# Using Addition Theorem for binomial identities

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

I know the addition theorem for binomial coefficients:

$\binom{x^*+y^*}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x^*}{n-k} \binom{y^*}{k}$

for $x^*,y^*\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Using this theorem i can prove identities such

$\binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2$ easily by applying $x^*=y^*=n$.

But what about the identity:

$\binom{x+y+n-1}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{x+n-k-1}{n-k} \binom{y+k-1}{k}$

Of course we see that it results from the Theorem but is it a problem that $k$ is "part of $x^*$ and $y^*$ here?

Comment: It's more 'Vandermonde identity' than 'addition theorem', just so you know.

Comment: thanks for the hint! Any idea if I can use it here?

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867972/proving-that-x-yn-1-choose-n-sum-k-0nxn-k-1-choose-n-kyk-1-ch.