# Combinatoric proof

Tags: combinatorics

I need to prove the following:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n\choose k}{m-1 \choose m-n+k} = {m+n-1 \choose m} $$

I have to prove it using combinatorics (not algebra).
I understand the right side is the number of ways to divide m balls into n different boxes, but how can I think about left side?

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure it can be shown using variants of the ['hockey stick identity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1) and probably [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867972/proving-that-x-yn-1-choose-n-sum-k-0nxn-k-1-choose-n-kyk-1-ch?noredirect=1&lq=1) one.

Answer (score 3):

The right hand equals $$\binom {m+n-1}{m+n-1-m}=\binom {m+n-1}{n-1}$$

Thus, the right hand is the number of ways to choose $n-1$ objects out of $m+n-1$.

Similarly we can rewrite one of the left hand factors as $$\binom {m-1}{m-n+k}=\binom {m-1}{(n-1)-k}$$

To see that the left hand is the same as the right, say we single out $n$ objects from the total.  Paint them blue and paint the others red. Note that there are $m+n-1-n=m-1$ red objects.  Now $k$ denotes the number of blue objects in our list of $n-1$.  Thus the $k^{th}$ term in your sum is the number of ways to choose $k$ blue and $(n-1)-k$ red objects out of $m+n-1$