# Prove equality involving binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was solving a probability problem and I got a different answer than the one given in the book. Seems the authors were using a different way of counting/arguing.

For the two answers to be equal, the following equality should hold true.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} \binom{a+k-1}{a-1} p^a (1-p)^k = \sum_{k=a}^{a+b-1} \binom {a+b-1}{k} p^{k} (1-p)^{a+b-k-1}$$

How can this be proved?

And the problem itself was: in a series of Bernoulli trials with probability for success in a single trial equal to $p$, what is the probability to get $a$ successes before getting $b$ failures?

I think you guys will reverse engineer how I counted and how the authors counted.

Comment: @callculus  I think the address function works even if there are no comments from the person in question.  Not sure about that...

Comment: @callculus  it works!  That is, I got notified of your comment.

Comment: @callculus  Ah, true.  I missed one.  But, on reflection, I sometimes cite other users responses to other posts and I use the address system to refer to them so they know they are being quoted.  That appears to work.

Comment: @lulu It sounds tricky.

Comment: @peter.petrov   Perhaps I am making arithmetic blunders but this seems false.  If we take $p=\frac 12$ and $a=b$ the answer should clearly be $\frac 12$ by symmetry.  If we take $a=b=2$ we do indeed get $\frac 12$ on the left, But on the right we get $\frac 68$.  Or have I messed it up?

Comment: @lulu Hmm, interesting. OK, I'll also try a few corner cases. By the way my answer is on the left. No wait, it is not 6/8, it is 4/8 on the right in that corner case you described.

Comment: I was able to verify it also for $a=2, b=4, p=1/2$. In this case both sides are equal to $13/16$. So it seems like it is a true equality indeed.

Comment: I was also able to verify it for $a=3, b=2, p=3/4$ Well, OK. I have no proof yet but at least I am more confident now in the correctness of my answer. It would be great if someone can provide a general proof. Interesting indeed...

Comment: Right, I had my example wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice question!

The short answer is: [You've already proved it!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_proof) By showing that the two sides are different counts of the same thing, you've proved that they're equal.

On the assumption that you're looking for an algebraic proof, here's a longer answer. Since on the left you only consider as many trials as you need until the result is decided, whereas on the right the authors consider all $a+b-1$ trials until the result is decided no matter what it is, we can transform your sum into their sum by adding the missing irrelevant $b-k-1$ trials:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}p^a(1-p)^k
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}p^a(1-p)^k1^{b-k-1}
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}p^a(1-p)^k(p+(1-p))^{b-k-1}
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}p^a(1-p)^k\sum_{j=0}^{b-k-1}\binom{b-k-1}jp^j(1-p)^{b-k-1-j}
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}\sum_{j=0}^{b-k-1}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}p^a(1-p)^k\binom{b-k-1}jp^j(1-p)^{b-k-1-j}
\\
&=&
\sum_{j=0}^{b-1}\sum_{k=0}^{b-j-1}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}p^a(1-p)^k\binom{b-k-1}jp^j(1-p)^{b-k-1-j}
\\
&=&
\sum_{j=0}^{b-1}p^ap^j(1-p)^{b-1-j}\sum_{k=0}^{b-j-1}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}\binom{b-k-1}j
\\
&=&
\sum_{j=0}^{b-1}p^ap^j(1-p)^{b-1-j}\sum_{k=0}^{b-j-1}\binom{b-k-1}{b-j-1-k}\binom{a+k-1}k
\\
&=&
\sum_{j=0}^{b-1}p^ap^j(1-p)^{b-1-j}\binom{a+b-1}{b-j-1}
\\
&=&
\sum_{j=0}^{b-1}p^ap^j(1-p)^{b-1-j}\binom{a+b-1}{a+j}
\\
&=&
\sum_{k=a}^{a+b-1}\binom{a+b-1}kp^k(1-p)^{a+b-k-1}\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

where the inner sum is evaluated using the relationship

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{x+n-k-1}{n-k}\binom{y+k-1}k=\binom{x+y+n-1}n\;,
$$

of which several proofs are given at [Proving that ${x +y+n- 1 \choose n}= \sum_{k=0}^n{x+n-k-1 \choose n-k}{y+k-1 \choose k} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867972).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation

Comment: (+1) I hope you don't mind that I posted my answer, which is essentially the same as yours, but with each step annotated.

Comment: @robjohn: No, sure, I upvoted it, the more the merrier :-)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't post this because joriki posted first and his answer is essentially the same (+1). However, since some explanation of the steps might be useful, I will post mine to provide an explanation for his steps.
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}p^a(1-p)^k\tag1\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}p^a(1-p)^k(p+(1-p))^{b-k-1}\tag2\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}\sum_{j=0}^{b-k-1}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}\binom{b-k-1}{j}p^a(1-p)^kp^j(1-p)^{b-j-k-1}\tag3\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{b-1}\sum_{k=0}^{b-j-1}\binom{a+k-1}{a-1}\binom{b-k-1}{j}p^{a+j}(1-p)^{b-j-1}\tag4\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{b-1}\binom{a+b-1}{a+j}p^{a+j}(1-p)^{b-j-1}\tag5\\
&=\sum_{j=a}^{a+b-1}\binom{a+b-1}{j}p^{j}(1-p)^{a+b-j-1}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: multiply by $1=(p+(1-p))^{b-k-1}$
$(3)$: apply the Binomial Theorem to $(p+(1-p))^{b-k-1}$
$(4)$: switch order of summation and combine terms
$(5)$: sum in $k$ using $\sum_{k=0}^{b-c}\binom{a+k}{a}\binom{b-k}{c}=\binom{a+b+1}{a+c+1}$
$(6)$: substitute $j\mapsto j-a$

Answer (score 1):

Starting from

$$\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} {a+k-1\choose a-1} p^a (1-p)^k
= \sum_{k=a}^{a+b-1} {a+b-1\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{a+b-k-1}$$

we simplify to

$$\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} {a+k-1\choose a-1} p^a (1-p)^k
= \sum_{k=0}^{b-1} {a+b-1\choose a+k} p^{a+k} (1-p)^{b-k-1}$$

or

$$\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} {a+k-1\choose a-1} (1-p)^k
= \sum_{k=0}^{b-1} {a+b-1\choose a+k} p^k (1-p)^{b-k-1}.$$

We get for the LHS

$$\sum_{k\ge 0} {a+k-1\choose a-1} (1-p)^k
[[0\le k\le b-1]]
\\ = \sum_{k\ge 0} {a+k-1\choose a-1} (1-p)^k
[z^{b-1}] \frac{z^k}{1-z}
\\ = [z^{b-1}] \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {a+k-1\choose a-1} (1-p)^k z^k
\\ = [z^{b-1}] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-(1-p)z)^a}.$$

The RHS is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} p^k (1-p)^{b-k-1}
[z^{b-1-k}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{a+k+1}}
\\ = [z^{b-1}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{a+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} p^k (1-p)^{b-k-1}
\frac{z^k}{(1-z)^{k}}.$$

There is  no contribution to  the coefficient extractor in  front when
$k\gt b-1$ and we may extend $k$ to infinity, getting

$$(1-p)^{b-1} [z^{b-1}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{a+1}}
\sum_{k\ge 0} p^k (1-p)^{-k}
\frac{z^k}{(1-z)^{k}}
\\ = (1-p)^{b-1} [z^{b-1}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{a+1}}
\frac{1}{1-pz/(1-p)/(1-z)}
\\ = (1-p)^{b-1} [z^{b-1}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^a}
\frac{1}{1-z-pz/(1-p)}
\\ =  [z^{b-1}] \frac{1}{(1-(1-p)z)^a}
\frac{1}{1-(1-p)z-pz}
\\ = [z^{b-1}] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-(1-p)z)^a}.$$

The LHS and the RHS are seen to be the same and we may conclude.

**Remark.**  The  first  one  is the  easy  one  and  follows  by
inspection. The Iverson bracket may be  of interest here as an example
of the method.